# Faster way to populate a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, asynchronous, populate

I have 4 sections in my tableview which contains 2500 cells each. This takes around 9 seconds to load. I would like to populate the 4 sections asynchronously, is this possible?

**EDIT:** The code for populating the tableview right now.

```
//Contains 2500 names each.
let namesForSection0:[String] = []
let namesForSection1:[String] = []
let namesForSection2:[String] = []
let namesForSection3:[String] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("catcell") as! UITableViewCell

    switch indexPath.section {

    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = namesForSection0[indexPath.row]

    case 2:
        cell.textLabel?.text = namesForSection1[indexPath.row]

    case 3:
        cell.textLabel?.text = namesForSection2[indexPath.row]

    case 4:
        cell.textLabel?.text = namesForSection3[indexPath.row]

    default:

        println("something is wrong")

    }

}
```

Comment: Show what the data is and how you're currently doing it. Have you profiled to see what is slow?

Comment: @Wain Code has been posted.

Comment: How are you calculating your cell heights?

Comment: @dan Other than using heightForRowAtIndexPath, all cells are height 44.

Comment: So which part is taking 4 seconds? Where do the strings come from?

Comment: @Wain 4 seconds? The data comes from a JSON-file which takes 1.2 seconds to load, and the "populating" takes the rest of the time up to 9 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, 9 seconds, you will need to do some profiling. The table only loads the visible cells so it shouldn't take any time at all.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing the JSON, first load the first 50 members or so for each of those arrays. Don't parse all of it at once. The arrays need to be mutable, aka `var namesForSection0:[String] = []`, not `let`. Reload the tableview.

Then parse the full JSON and add new members to the arrays. Be sure not to add duplicates (this is specific to your data). After they are loaded, call reloadData on your tableview.